# Testing Chained Promises (Jasmine, React, Karma)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I have run into several situations on my present project where I have a chain of promises that I'm not sure how to deal with.

Here is the relevant code block:

```
    return this.axios.get(path, requestOpts)
        .then((response) => {console.log('did authorize: ', response); return response})
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.ok) {
                window.localStorage.setItem(path, JSON.stringify(response.data));
                console.log("Setting localStorage item ", path, response.data);

                return response.data.payloadUrl;
            } else {
                console.error("Non-ok response for ", path, response.data);
                const resp: DisplayTokenResponse = response.data;

                //TODO: reject promise?
                if (resp.status === "AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED") {
                    this.axiosService.goToLoginPage(window.location + '');
                }

                Promise.reject(response.data.message);
            }
        });
```

My test (so far) looks like this:

```
describe('.authorize()', () => {
    let axiosSpy: jasmine.Spy;

    beforeEach((done) => {
        spyOn(svc, 'keyPath').and.returnValue(path);
        spyOn(svc, 'storedToken').and.returnValue(stored);

        let response = {
            data: {
                ok: true,
                message: 'test-response',
                payloadUrl: 'http://payload-url.com'
            }
        }



        spyOn(svc.axios, 'get').and.callFake(
            (path:string, reqOpts:AxiosRequestConfig) => {
                return new Promise(() => {
                    response
                });
            }, (e) => {
                console.log(`failed`);
            });
    });

    describe('should authorize user', () => {
        it('when supplied a STRING', () => {
            clientId = clientId_string;
        });
        it('when supplied a NUMBER', () => {
            clientId = clientId_number;
        });

        afterEach((done) => {
            svc.authorize(clientId, locationId, screenId).then((result) => {
                console.log(`result ${result}`);
                done();
            }, (e) => {
                console.log(`failed with error ${e}`);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I can test one-level-down promises, but how to I set up my tests to be able to handle situations like this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what "situation" you referring too? Also, you have always to return a Promise from a `then` block if you want the rejection to be noticeable from outside -> `**return** Promise.reject(response.data.message);`

Comment: I mean when a Promise is chained through multiple ``.then`` statements like this. I am trying to verify that it resolves at each step. When I try to mock the response from the initial promise from ```this.axios.get```, the test times out without returning anything. Based on the logs, it never seems to make it to the accept/reject stage of the second ``.then``.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it figured out. I believe it stemmed from a confusion between creating Promise instances versus their resolvers.

The new beforeEach block looks like this:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        spyOn(svc, 'keyPath').and.returnValue(path);
        spyOn(svc, 'storedToken').and.returnValue(stored);

        let axiosPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var responseData = {
                data: {
                    ok: true,
                    message: 'test-response',
                    payloadUrl: 'http://payload-url.com'
                }
            };

            resolve(responseData);
        });

        spyOn(svc.axios, 'get').and.callFake(
            ()=>{
                return axiosPromise;
            }
        );
    });
```

My tests now pass.